# Create a detail listing page of a record on admin side

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, model

I want to create a page like an edit page of an model where user cannot change any content. He can only see the content. How can i achieve it?

Comment: In magento backend  ? and you want to like to all user or specific user?

Comment: For all users .

Comment: In form you can disable field so any user cant change value. like: https://niravkadiya.wordpress.com/2013/02/22/display-admin-form-field-only-readonly-in-magento/